# Convert FileIncludes to file filter predicate

Tags: f#-fake

I'm trying to use `CopyDir` to copy my build artifacts to an output directory.

I'm not sure how I am supposed to define the filter predicate that `CopyDir` takes as an argument. I've looked in the documentation and tried searching for many different keywords on Google.

`Target "Copy-Build-Output" (fun _ ->
    let baseDir = (sourceDir + @"Trunk\Webroot")
    let outputfiles =
        !! (sourceDir @@ "**/*.*")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.cs")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.csproj")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.vspscc")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.cssscc")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "web.config")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "bin/*.xml")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "obj/**")
    CopyDir outputDir baseDir ???? 
)`

How do I take the file include set and convert it into a matching statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need to create separate target for copying output while you can set up output directory in build target itself as follow (example for MSBUILD) . 
you can set path like OutDir and sourcecode path according to location of build script (example for build script at the root of application)

```
 Target "Build" (fun _ -> 
!! "**/*.csproj"
-- "**/*.Tests.csproj"
    |> MSBuildRelease OutDir "Rebuild"
    |> Log "Building Projects: "
```

please refer http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-msbuildhelper.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy every file (eg. `*.*`) a filter predicate of `(fun x -> true)` is enough.

```
Target "Copy-Build-Output" (fun _ ->
    let baseDir = (sourceDir + @"Trunk\Webroot")
    let outputfiles =
        !! (sourceDir @@ "**/*.*")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.cs")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.csproj")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.vspscc")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "**/*.cssscc")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "web.config")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "bin/*.xml")
          -- (sourceDir @@ "obj/**")
    CopyDir outputDir baseDir (fun x -> true)
)
```

The filter predicate is a function `string -> bool`. That is any function taking a `string` as input and returning a `bool`.

So for copying only `.png` images you could use `(fun x -> x.EndsWith(".png"))`.

There is probably other methods for specifying files. But this work for me.